# Kohana v3 database, how to get table structure?

Tags: php, mysql, database, kohana

How can I using KohanaPHP framework and database module get mysql table structure?

I've tried this:

```
$query = DB::query(NULL, 'DESCRIBE table_name');
$result = $query->execute();
```

But it only returns number of columns in table, and foreach loop failed.

Is there any other way to get table structure or how can I update code above to works properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = DB::query(NULL, 'SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name');
$result = $query->execute();
```

**EDIT**

You need to specify the type of query of DB::query() will just return the number of affected rows.

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name');
$result = $query->execute();
```

This will give you the result you expect.

Comment: The same situation like with "DESCRIBE". MySQL query is ok in both case, but it doesn't work in kohana...

Comment: What happens when you set the first paramater of DB::query() to Database::SELECT

Comment: @Mr Sooul I have updated my answer. this should fix your issue.

Comment: Oh, it works like I want :) Thanks for solution. How can I skip that? :( Probably becouse I didn't need type of query when I was checking if table exists...